# conda update --all fail

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to update anaconda on my machine but get the following:

```
         (base) Chriss-MBP:opt chrisgaughan$ pwd
         /opt
         (base) Chriss-MBP:opt chrisgaughan$ ls -la
          total 0
          drwxr-xr-x   5 root          wheel  160 Mar 24 18:05 .
          drwxr-xr-x  22 root          admin  704 Jul 17 12:16 ..
          drwxr-xr-x   9 root          wheel  288 Sep 27  2016 X11
          drwxr-xr-x   2 chrisgaughan  wheel   64 Jul 28 22:27 anaconda3
          drwxr-xr-x  11 root          wheel  352 Jun  9 12:40 local
          (base) Chriss-MBP:opt chrisgaughan$ sudo conda update --all
          Password:
          Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

          UnavailableInvalidChannel: The channel is not accessible or is invalid.
          channel name: vpython/vpython-jupyter
          channel url: https://github.com/vpython/vpython-jupyter
          error code: 404
          You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
          Use `conda config --show channels` to view your configuration's current state,
          and use `conda config --show-sources` to view config file locations.
```

can someone please lend a suggestion? I have very limited knowledge on this particular area

Comment: Can you share the packages in the environment?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is a problem in access to the `vpython` channel (packages repository). If this package were available from another channel - you may switch channels by editing the config file ( find its location by running `conda config --show channels`). Most likely this is not the case and the package is unique - then I suggest to wait (ofthen such problems go away fast) or contact the channel maintainers - see https://vpython.org/

Comment: Thank you, Komrade (Russian S.)